# I'm Having trouble accesing my data in firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

im getting this two errors in my debug console (core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false) and (Could not reach Firestore backend.) In my firestore data i ve got a Collection "Recipes" and then in de documents i ve got each recipe with its own attribute.
Here i leave you a sneek peek of the code.

```
new StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Recipes').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                _buildListRecipe(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
          );
        });
```

Then in my _buildListRecipe I'm accessing each in the value of each recipe.

```
new Image.network(

            document["firstImage"],

            width: double.infinity,
            height: 150.0,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),﻿
```

Comment: show a screenshort of your collection and of permissions in your collection. Also, do you authenticate with firebase?

Comment: "Could not reach" means that no connectivity could be established, which also tells you that your code is irrelevant. The problem is all about your connection to the "backend".

Answer (score 0):

did you resolve your issue and do you remember how?  I reach the exact same problem, I don't found any response or tips to resolve it.

Here, a bit of me code :

```
  void _listenToUserDatabase(String key) async {
    _userStream = _usersDatabase.child(key).onValue.listen((event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        final String source = jsonEncode(event.snapshot.value);
        final Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(source);
        _user = UserModel.fromJson(json, key: key);
        _userKey = key;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }, onError: (e) {
      print("Listen to user database error $e");
    }, onDone: () {
      print("listen done");
    });
  }
```